# Dynamic add images in on last imageview click Grid view

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am new to android and dont know how to use gridview .I want grid view in below image format at the end of the item there should an imageview  when I click n that i should add imageview before the last imageview in grid view.This gridview have imageview,s.It shuld add imageview dynamically.
Please Help

[image: Grid view]

Comment: r u using a custom adapter to set grid view data??

Answer (score 0):

- The `GridView` is backed by an adapter. Look at `BaseAdapter` or `ListAdapter`
- The adapter is backed by a dataset such as a list
- You use the adapter's `getView()` function to generate views for a given position in the dataset

All you need to do is create a list that has N+1 elements in it, where N is the number of images you want to display and the +1 is for the add button.

When an image is added, you add it to the list at the second-last position. You then call the adapters `notifyDataSetChanged()` function. This will refresh the GridView with the new backing data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following adaper:

in activity:

```
private List<Bitmap> images=new List<Bitmap>();
images.add(<LastImage>);
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,images);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

While adding a new item:

```
adapter.addImage(<NewBitmap>);
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {

    private List<Bitmap> images;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context,
            List<Bitmap> images) {
        super(context,0, images);
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView;
        if (image == null) {
            image = new ImageView(context);
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }

    public void addImage(Bitmap image) {
        images.add(images.size()-1,image);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```